# Dynamic array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I have such piece of code:

```
typedef struct reader
{
    char name[50];
    char card_num[50];
    char title[100];
}reader_t;
int main()
{
    vector<reader> vec;
    ifstream input_file("D:\\lab.txt", ios::binary);
    reader_t master[1];
    input_file.read((char*)&master, sizeof(master));

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 1; idx++)
    {
        reader temp;
        strcpy(temp.name, master[idx].name);
        strcpy(temp.card_num, master[idx].card_num);
        strcpy(temp.title, master[idx].title);
        vec.push_back(temp);

        cout << "Name: " << master[idx].name << endl;
        cout << "Card num: " << master[idx].card_num << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << master[idx].title<<endl;

    }
    cout << vec.size();

    getchar();
}
```

What is does: it reads structures from binary file into an array of structures,copies them into vector and displays structure.And yes, I do need to do like this - I need to store structures from file in vector and this is the only working way to do it I could find(if you can tell, how to read structures to vector directly from file - you are welcome).

So,everything works fine, but the problem is that I need to create a function which would be able to do the same, but with dynamic array.I wrote something like this:

```
void read_structs(int vec_size)
{
     ifstream input_file("D:\\lab.txt", ios::binary);

     //Here I commented 2 ways how I tried to create a dynamic array of structs
     //reader* master = new reader[vec_size];
     //reader* master = (reader*)malloc(sizeof(reader) * vec_size);

    input_file.read((char*)&master, sizeof(master));
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < vec_size; idx++)
    {

        reader temp;
        strcpy(temp.name, master[idx].name);
        strcpy(temp.card_num, master[idx].card_num);
        strcpy(temp.title, master[idx].title);
        vec.push_back(temp);

        cout << "Name: " << master[idx].name << endl;
        cout << "Card num: " << master[idx].card_num << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << master[idx].title<<endl;

    }
 }
```

And that worked fine too unless I tried to run it.VS wasn't higlighting error in my code, it just was throwing an exception right as the moment when the program tried to access master[0].name.

Comment: What is value of `vec_size` ?

Comment: @ameyCU when I run the program I use 1

Comment: Just use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Try sizeof(reader)*vec_size instead of sizeof(master)

Comment: @StoryTeller I've already written in post why I can't just use vector

Comment: No, what you've written in the post is that you don't understand how to use `std::vector` for a certain purpose. That's the easiest limitation to overcome, read the documentation.

Comment: Also, vector already creates a copy, no need to use temp. You can just do vec.push_back(master[idx]);

Comment: you make 1 struct temp. read the number of bytes = sizeof(struct) into the struct, make a vector std::vector<struct> and push_back into the vector. I dont understand why you read the whole file into master

Comment: @rinn2883 well, I read the whole file into master because file contains only 1 structure

Comment: unrelated, `struct reader {...};` is enough in C++, `typedef` version is `C` legacy. You even mess with `reader` and `reader_t` names in your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is absolutely no point in the `temp` struct. See, the

   ```
   vec.push_back(temp);
   ```

   is already using copy constructor, so copy constructor must work and then the set of `strcpy` is not doing anything different from that, so just go with

   ```
   vec.push_back(master[0]).
   ```
2. You can't read into vector directly. You do need to read into temporary. So that is correct. Except I suppose you want to read all entries from the file no matter how many of them there are, so you need to put the read itself also into the loop.
3. There is not much point in creating an array of one element.

   ```
   reader_t master[1];
   input_file.read((char*)master, sizeof(master));
   //                     ^ you *don't* need & here, arrays degrade to pointers automatically
   ```

   and

   ```
   reader_t master;
   input_file.read((char *)&master, sizeof(master));
   //                      ^ but you do need & here.
   ```

   are equivalent. I would go with the later.
4. So we are basically down to:

   ```
   reader temp; // calling it temp; the master name makes no sense.
   while (input_file.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(temp)))
   // read returns input_file and input_file is false if last operation failed
   {
       vec.push_back(temp);

       // verify the stored values by reading back vfrom vec.back().
       cout << "Name: " << vec.back().name << endl;
       cout << "Card num: " << vec.back().card_num << endl;
       cout << "Title: " << vec.back().title<<endl;
   }
   ```
5. In the second example, you didn't initialize `master`, so it obviously crashed.
6. **There is a more C++ approach though.** First, you define a read operator for the structure:

   ```
   std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, reader &r) {
       return in.read((char *)&r, sizeof(r));
   }
   ```

   and then you simply read the vector using the [istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

   ```
   vec.assign(std::istream_iterator<reader>(input_file),
              std::istream_iterator<reader>());
   ```

   and the standard library will generate the above loop for you.

Comment: yep that is what i said in comment, ty for typing it out in steps. Idk if you initialized master somewhere else. Else you need to print with temp.name etc.. and you dont need master anymore.

Comment: or print with the vector like the edit is also an option.

Comment: @NightStallion, you'll have to do some debugging. Does the file actually have all the bytes? Remember, it is exactly 50 bytes for name, exactly 50 bytes for card_num and exactly 100 bytes for title. If you meant newline-terminated or something, you'll need to do correct formatted input in the `operator>>`.

Comment: @JanHudec yep,exactly 200 bytes

Comment: @JanHudec  well,I tried to do like you wrote in 6th paragraph,but I get this error:C2664: "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<reader>>> std::vector<reader,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<reader>>>,unsigned int,const _Ty &)": can not convert argument 1 from "std::istream_iterator<reader,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>" into "std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<reader>>>"

Comment: @NightStallion, that's what one gets for writing off the top of their head. But you should be able to fix it ;-) (hint: the intended overload of `insert` has 3 arguments; alternately you can use `assign`).

Comment: @JanHudec oh,great,that finally worked!Thanks a lot!